# NGRX 8, angular, how to handle undefined error

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have problem with below selector:

```
export const selectInfoFromMap = createSelector(featureSelector, (state, props) =>
    state.attributes.get(props.userName).get(props.parameterUser).userValue);
```

During initializing of component, below map is not existing. I can easily check the null value.

```
export const selectInfoFromMap = createSelector(featureSelector, (state, props) =>
    state.attributes.get(props.userName).get(props.parameterUser).userValue ?
        state.attributes.get(props.userName).get(props.parameterUser).userValue : '0.0');
```

But, there is a possibilty to check undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is deep drill down on properties, you better of use try catch

```
export const selectInfoFromMap = createSelector(featureSelector, (state, props) =>{

   try{ 
      return state.attributes.get(props.userName).get(props.parameterUser).userValue
    }catch(e){
        return '0.0'
}
```